# Thunderbird update failed

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird

On Windows 10 18.03 the Thunderbird update from V38.5.0 fails with the following message:

```
The update could not be installed. Please make sure there are no other
copies of Thunderbird running on your computer, and then restart
Thunderbird to try again.
```

I did that (there was no 2nd copy), I looked in the Task Manager, I even rebooted. But I always have the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if one of the folders Thunderbird uses is locked or owned by someone other than that who did the installation. Try starting Thunderbird by right-clicking on the Thunderbird icon and select `Run as Administrator`. Then go to `Help` | `About Thunderbird` and it should update correctly.

Another possibility is that some other program, e.g. *Cortana* indexing, is currently accessing the profile folder. Check the folder `C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles` with a tool such as [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/) to see what is causing the issue.

[image: LockHunter in action]

Then either use the tool to end the process to unlock the folder or perform a full reboot, not hybrid shutdown, to unlock it.

If none of these worked, then save your personal data in the profile, uninstall Thunderbird, perform a [fresh installation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1085697) and then [restore your data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/thunderbird/download-install-and-migration). Before this drastic measure, *back up all Thunderbird data in `User\AppData`.*

Comment: Thanks, running Thunderbird as administrator saved me a new installation that I already had considered.